# Zoom one image from click of some other image

Tags: jquery, css, html

```
<div>
   <img src="1.jpg">
   <img src="2.jpg">
</div>

<div>
   <img src="3.jpg">
   <img src="4.jpg">
</div>
```

Requirement is like this - on click of image'2.jpg' image '1.jpg' should get zoomed ,on click of image'4.jpg' image'3.jpg' should get zoomed and so forth .There can be any number of these div . Image 2/4/6 ... are dynamic images . Images 1/3/5 ... are like static zoom icon.

```
$(function() {
```

What i have done till now

```
$('img').on('click', function() {

 $('.zoomImageClass').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));

 $('#zoomImageId').modal('show');
});
```

});

But here clicked image is getting zoomed . I want that image to be zoomed for which zoom icon is clicked .

Comment: `I want that image to be zoomed for which zoom icon is clicked .` => where is zoom icon HTML? please share it too. (edit your question and add it)

Comment: queryselectorall('.img:nth-child(1)')...

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <img class="sourceImageClass" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  <img class="zoomImageClass" src="http://via.placeholder.com/5x5">
</div>

<div>
  <img class="sourceImageClass" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
  <img class="zoomImageClass" src="http://via.placeholder.com/5x5">
</div>

<img id="zoomImageId">
```

and then in JS

```
$(function() {
    $("div img.zoomImageClass").each(function(i,el){
        $(el).click(function(){
        console.log($(el).attr("src"));
      var imageURL=$(el).parent().find(".sourceImageClass").attr("src");
      $("#zoomImageId").attr("src", imageURL)
    });
  });
});
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hanalulu/trpdqxac/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood your question - I'll remove my answer is so, but it looks to me like you're over-complicating this. Here's an example making use of jQuery's `siblings` .

```js
$(function() {
  $('div > img:last-child').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings("img:first-child").toggleClass("zoom");
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.zoom {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/An_Indian_tiger_in_the_wild._Royal%2C_Bengal_tiger_%2827466438332%29.jpg/1200px-An_Indian_tiger_in_the_wild._Royal%2C_Bengal_tiger_%2827466438332%29.jpg">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/An_Indian_tiger_in_the_wild._Royal%2C_Bengal_tiger_%2827466438332%29.jpg/1200px-An_Indian_tiger_in_the_wild._Royal%2C_Bengal_tiger_%2827466438332%29.jpg">
</div>

<div>
   <img src="http://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/inline-images/tiger_amur_snow.jpg">
   <img src="http://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/inline-images/tiger_amur_snow.jpg">
</div>
```